# Handling Julian days in C++11/14

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-chrono, julian-date

What is the best/easiest way to deal with [Julian days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) in C++?  I want to be able to convert between Julian days and Gregorian dates.  I have C++11 and C++14.  Can the `<chrono>` library help with this problem?

Comment: Please, forgive my pedantic suggestion: s/ _Julian date_ / _Julian day_ . Similarly to _Gregorian date_, _Julian date_ sounds to me as a "_date in the Julian calendar_". It's unfortunate that these (related but different) concepts have confusingly close names.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks.  I've edited both the question and answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To convert between a [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) and `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` the first thing one needs to do is find out the difference between the epochs.

The `system_clock` has no official epoch, but the de facto standard epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (Gregorian calendar).  For convenience, it is handy to state the [Julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) epoch in terms of the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar).  This calendar extends the current rules backwards, and includes a year 0.  This makes the arithmetic easier, but one has to take care to convert years BC into negative years by subtracting 1 and negating (e.g. 2BC is year -1).  The [Julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) epoch is -4713-11-24 12:00:00 UTC (roughly speaking).

The `<chrono>` library can conveniently handle time units on this scale.  Additionally, [this date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) can conveniently convert between Gregorian dates and `system_clock::time_point`.  To find the difference between these two epochs is simply:

```
constexpr
auto
jdiff()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    return sys_days{January/1/1970} - (sys_days{November/24/-4713} + 12h);
}
```

This returns a `std::chrono::duration` with a period of hours.  In C++14 this can be `constexpr` and we can use the chrono duration literal `12h` instead of `std::chrono::hours{12}`.

If you don't want to use the [date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), this is just a constant number of hours and can be rewritten to this more cryptic form:

```
constexpr
auto
jdiff()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    return 58574100h;
}
```

Either way you write it, the efficiency is identical.  This is just a function that returns the constant `58574100`.  This could also be a `constexpr` global, but then you have to leak your using declarations, or decide not to use them.

Next it is handy to create a Julian day clock (`jdate_clock`).  Since we need to deal with units at least as fine as a half a day, and it is common to express julian dates as floating point days, I will make the `jdate_clock::time_point` a count of double-based days from the epoch:

```
struct jdate_clock
{
    using rep        = double;
    using period     = std::ratio<86400>;
    using duration   = std::chrono::duration<rep, period>;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<jdate_clock>;

    static constexpr bool is_steady = false;

    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        return time_point{duration{system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()} + jdiff()};
    }
};
```

Implementation note:

> I converted the return from `system_clock::now()` to `duration` immediately to avoid overflow for those systems where `system_clock::duration` is nanoseconds.

`jdate_clock` is now a fully conforming and fully functioning `<chrono>` clock.  For example I can find out what time it is now with:

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << jdate_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
```

which just output:

```
2457354.310832
```

This is a type-safe system in that `jdate_clock::time_point` and `system_clock::time_point` are two distinct types which one can not accidentally perform mixed arithmetic in.  And yet you can still get all of the rich benefits from the `<chrono>` library, such as add and subtract durations to/from your `jdate_clock::time_point`.

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto jnow = jdate_clock::now();
auto jpm = jnow + 1min;
auto jph = jnow + 1h;
auto tomorrow = jnow + 24h;
auto diff = tomorrow - jnow;
assert(diff == 24h);
```

But if I accidentally said:

```
auto tomorrow = system_clock::now() + 24h;
auto diff = tomorrow - jnow;
```

I would get an error such as this:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression
  ('std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long,
  std::ratio<1, 1000000> > >' and 'std::chrono::time_point<jdate_clock, std::chrono::duration<double,
  std::ratio<86400, 1> > >')
auto diff = tomorrow - jnow;
            ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~
```

In English:  You can't subtract a `jdate_clock::time_point` from a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.

But sometimes I **do** want to convert a `jdate_clock::time_point` to a `system_clock::time_point` or vice-versa.  For that one can easily write a couple of helper functions:

```
template <class Duration>
constexpr
auto
sys_to_jdate(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration> tp) noexcept
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    static_assert(jdate_clock::duration{jdiff()} < Duration::max(),
                  "Overflow in sys_to_jdate");
    const auto d = tp.time_since_epoch() + jdiff();
    return time_point<jdate_clock, std::remove_cv_t<decltype(d)>>{d};
}

template <class Duration>
constexpr
auto
jdate_to_sys(std::chrono::time_point<jdate_clock, Duration> tp) noexcept
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    static_assert(jdate_clock::duration{-jdiff()} > Duration::min(),
                  "Overflow in jdate_to_sys");
    const auto d = tp.time_since_epoch() - jdiff();
    return time_point<system_clock, std::remove_cv_t<decltype(d)>>{d};
}
```

Implementation note:

> I've added static range checking which is likely to fire if you use nanoseconds or a 32bit-based minute as a duration in your source `time_point`.

The general recipe is to get the `duration` since the epoch (`duration`s are "clock neutral"), add or subtract the offset between the epochs, and then convert the `duration` into the desired `time_point`.

These will convert among the two clock's `time_point`s using *any* precision, all in a type-safe manner.  If it compiles, it works.  If you made a programming error, it shows up at compile time.  Valid example uses include:

```
auto tp = sys_to_jdate(system_clock::now());
```

`tp` is a `jdate::time_point` except that it has integral representation with the precision of whatever your `system_clock::duration` is (for me that is microseconds).  Be forewarned that if it is nanoseconds for you (gcc), this will overflow as nanoseconds only has a range of +/- 292 years.

You can force the precision like so:

```
auto tp = sys_to_jdate(time_point_cast<hours>(system_clock::now()));
```

And now `tp` is an integral count of hours since the `jdate` epoch.

If you are willing to use [this date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), one can easily use the utilities above to convert a floating point julian date into a Gregorian date, with any accuracy you want.  For example:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace date;
std::cout << std::fixed;
auto jtp = jdate_clock::time_point{jdate_clock::duration{2457354.310832}};
auto tp = floor<seconds>(jdate_to_sys(jtp));
std::cout << "Julian day " << jtp.time_since_epoch().count()
          << " is " << tp << " UTC\n";
```

We use our `jdate_clock` to create a `jdate_clock::time_point`.  Then we use our `jdate_to_sys` conversion function to convert `jtp` into a `system_clock::time_point`.  This will have a representation of double and a period of hours.  That isn't really important though.  What *is* important is to convert it into whatever representation and precision you *want*.  I've done that above with `floor<seconds>`.  I also could have used `time_point_cast<seconds>` and it would have done the same thing.  `floor` comes from [the date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), always truncates towards negative infinity, and is easier to spell.

This will output:

```
Julian day 2457354.310832 is 2015-11-27 19:27:35 UTC
```

If I wanted to round to the nearest second instead of floor, that would simply be:

```
auto tp = round<seconds>(jdate_to_sys(jtp));
Julian date 2457354.310832 is 2015-11-27 19:27:36 UTC
```

Or if I wanted it to the nearest millisecond:

```
auto tp = round<milliseconds>(jdate_to_sys(jtp));
Julian day 2457354.310832 is 2015-11-27 19:27:35.885 UTC
```

### Update for C++17

The `floor` and `round` functions mentioned above as part of [Howard Hinnant's date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) are now also available under namespace `std::chrono` as part of C++17.

### Update for C++20

[Howard Hinnant's date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) was largely voted into C++20, and so `jdate_clock` can now be written entirely in terms of `std::chrono`.

Additionally there is a handy `std::chrono::clock_cast` feature which `jdate_clock` can participate in.  This facilitates the conversion between `time_point`s of different clocks, and can even help in the implementation of `jdate_clock`:

```
#include <chrono>

struct jdate_clock;

template <class Duration>
    using jdate_time = std::chrono::time_point<jdate_clock, Duration>;

struct jdate_clock
{
    using rep        = double;
    using period     = std::chrono::days::period;
    using duration   = std::chrono::duration<rep, period>;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<jdate_clock>;

    static constexpr bool is_steady = false;

    static time_point now() noexcept;

    template <class Duration>
    static
    auto
    from_sys(std::chrono::sys_time<Duration> const& tp) noexcept;

    template <class Duration>
    static
    auto
    to_sys(jdate_time<Duration> const& tp) noexcept;
};

template <class Duration>
auto
jdate_clock::from_sys(std::chrono::sys_time<Duration> const& tp) noexcept
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;
    auto constexpr epoch = sys_days{November/24/-4713} + 12h;
    using ddays = std::chrono::duration<long double, days::period>;
    if constexpr (sys_time<ddays>{sys_time<Duration>::min()} < sys_time<ddays>{epoch})
    {
        return jdate_time{tp - epoch};
    }
    else
    {
        // Duration overflows at the epoch.  Sub in new Duration that won't overflow.
        using D = std::chrono::duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 10'000'000>>;
        return jdate_time{round<D>(tp) - epoch};
    }
}

template <class Duration>
auto
jdate_clock::to_sys(jdate_time<Duration> const& tp) noexcept
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return sys_time{tp - clock_cast<jdate_clock>(sys_days{})};
}

jdate_clock::time_point
jdate_clock::now() noexcept
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return clock_cast<jdate_clock>(system_clock::now());
}
```

`jdate_time` is simply a convenience type alias written in the style of new convenience type alias provided by `std::chrono`.  It shortens some of the signatures in the implementation of `jdate_clock` and makes it easier for clients to make `time_point`s of `jdate_clock` with arbitrary `duration`s.

There are two new `static` member functions of `jdate_clock`: `from_sys` and `to_sys`.  These take place of the previous namespace scope functions `sys_to_jdate` and `jdate_to_sys`.  `from_sys` and `to_sys` are what enables `jdate_clock` to participate in the `std::chrono::clock_cast` facility.

`clock_cast` looks for these static member functions and uses them to convert between `jdate_clock` and *every other* clock, chrono-defined or not, that participates in the `clock_cast` facility.

`now()` can simply `clock_cast` from `system_clock::now()` to return the current time.

`from_sys` simply subtracts the given `system_clock`-based `time_point` and the Julian epoch: -4713-11-24 12:00:00 UTC.  The return type must be at least as fine as hours since the epoch has a precision of hours.

However, there is a complication:  Since the epoch is so far in the past, some common measures, such as `sys_time<nanoseconds>` overflow this far back.  So a `constexpr` test is done to see if the `sys_time<Duration>` will overflow.  If it does, a new `Duration` is subbed in that is known to not overflow.

`to_sys` can reuse the epoch in `from_sys` by using `clock_cast` to find the Julian date at the system_clock epoch:  `clock_cast<jdate_clock>(sys_days{})`.  This is subtracted from the Julian date to find the time since the `system_clock` epoch.

The client code can now use the generic `clock_cast` in place of the less generic `jdate_to_sys` API:

```
using namespace std::chrono;

auto jtp = jdate_clock::time_point{jdate_clock::duration{2457354.310832}};
auto tp = round<milliseconds>(clock_cast<system_clock>(jtp));
std::cout << "Julian day " << jtp.time_since_epoch()
          << " is " << tp << " UTC\n";
```

Output:

```
Julian date 2457354.310832d is 2015-11-27 19:27:35.885 UTC
```

And finally note that although `jdate_clock` knows nothing about `std::chrono::tai_clock`, `clock_cast` can *still* convert to and from it as well.

```
auto jtp = jdate_clock::time_point{jdate_clock::duration{2457354.310832}};
auto tp = round<milliseconds>(clock_cast<tai_clock>(jtp));
std::cout << "Julian day " << jtp.time_since_epoch()
          << " is " << tp << " TAI\n";
```

Output:

```
Julian day 2457354.310832d is 2015-11-27 19:28:11.885 TAI
```

Comment: +1 to the question. I haven't for the answer because it recalls to me some traits of sponsorship. The fact that you also provide a pure C++ version evens the average rating, though. Just my objective view.

Comment: @black:  No problem.  Fwiw, the date library (sponsorship) is free, open-source, MIT license, github repository.  And here are the public-domain algorithms the date library is based on: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html (in case you would rather build your own date library).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Howard for providing these helpful examples. I ended up using slightly modified versions of the sys_to_jdate and jdate_to_sys functions in order to successfully compile using MSVC/C++17. The original forms did compile using clang 12.0.0.12000032 and gcc 8.3.1.

```
template <class Duration>
constexpr
auto
sys_to_jdate_v2(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration> tp) noexcept
{
    static_assert(jdate_clock::duration{jdiff()} < Duration::max(),
                  "Overflow in sys_to_jdate");
    const auto d = jdate_clock::duration{tp.time_since_epoch() + jdiff()};
    return jdate_clock::time_point{d};
}

template <class Duration>
constexpr
auto
jdate_to_sys_v2(std::chrono::time_point<jdate_clock, Duration> tp) noexcept
{
    static_assert(jdate_clock::duration{-jdiff()} > Duration::min(),
                  "Overflow in jdate_to_sys");
    const auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>(tp.time_since_epoch() - jdiff());
    return std::chrono::system_clock::time_point{d};
}
```

The above modifications made the following compile error disappear:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\chrono(182,23): error C2338: duration must be an instance of std::duration
```

(apparently provoked by the last line of jdate_to_sys)

I am very new to chrono and date APIs, so would welcome input as to the correctness of my fixes.

Comment: Removing the `const` from the declaration of `d` also works.  It turns out that you may have stumbled over a bug in the standards spec, or in one of the std::lib implementations.  I'm not sure yet.  Investigating....

Comment: It looks like the bug is in my answer and llvm's libc++ where I tested my answer.  I've updated `sys_to_jdate` and `jdate_to_sys` with `remove_cv_t` to fix the bug.

Comment: @HowardHinnant thank you investigating and proposing a fix. I have confirmed that the updated code compiles using clang 12.0.0.12000032, gcc 8.3.1, and MSVC 14.28.29333.