# How to use clock_cast?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I would like to convert time points from different clocks. Currently I follow the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361638/converting-steady-clocktime-point-to-time-t).

```
static auto ref_sys_clk = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
static auto ref_std_clk = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

auto to_sys_clk(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp)
{
    //return std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock::time_point>(tp);
    return ref_sys_clk + std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>(tp - ref_std_clk);
}
```

How can I utilize [`clock_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/clock_cast) for this purpose. Currently I use Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Your question is tagged C++11, but `clock_cast` is a C++20 feature. Do you want an answer for C++20?

Comment: Yes, I added the c++20 tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` does not participate in the `std::chrono::clock_cast` facility.  The reason for this is that `high_resolution_clock`, has no portable relationship to any human calendar.  It *might* have one on some platforms, notably if it is a type alias for `system_clock`.  But it definitely does not on all platforms.

Here is a list of clocks that participate in the `clock_cast` infrastructure:

- `std::chrono::system_clock`
- `std::chrono::utc_clock`
- `std::chrono::tai_clock`
- `std::chrono::gps_clock`
- `std::chrono::file_clock`
- Any user-written clock that supplies the static member functions `to_sys`/`from_sys`, or `to_utc`/`from_utc`.

See the **Update for C++20** section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33964462/576911) for an example of how to add these functions for your custom clock.

Any clock that does not have the static member functions `to_sys`/`from_sys`, or `to_utc`/`from_utc` will fail to compile when used in a `clock_cast` as either the source or destination.

Here is an example use of `clock_cast` being used to convert from a `system_clock`-based `time_point` to a `utc_clock`-based `time_point` at a precision of `milliseconds`.

```
auto t = sys_days{July/1/2015} - 500ms;
auto u = clock_cast<utc_clock>(t);
```

Comment: Thanks, even if I am out of luck with clock_cast and high_resolution_clock.

Answer (score 3):

`std::clock_cast` is new in C++20, so if you have a C++11 implementation, you are out of luck. Some implementations still haven't fully implemented C++20, so you may still be out of luck. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a feature test macro defined for `std::clock_cast`, so you will have to check your complier's documentation.

The first parameter of `std::chrono::clock_cast` is the destination *clock*, not the desired *time_point*.

```
auto to_sys_clk(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp)
{
    return std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(tp);
}
```

Comment: as far as I can see neither libstdc++ nor libc++ have `clock_cast` yet.

Comment: @bolov and no feature test macro in the proposal :(