# MacOS std::chrono::clock_cast not found

Tags: c++, macos, c++20, clang++, c++-chrono

I am trying to use the new C++20 chrono library, more specifically the new `clock_cast`.

If I compile on Linux with clang++ `16.0.6` it works as expected.
However, if I try to compile on MacOS I encounter the following error:

```
error: no member named 'clock_cast' in namespace 'std::chrono'
```

Clang is version `17.0.5` on the Mac, so I would expect the chrono library to be implemented, do I need to add another include?
I couldn't find anything online about this issue.

Clang version:

```
Homebrew clang version 17.0.5
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
```

Also tried with the default xcode clang version, same error.

Minimum reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    auto time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto system_time = std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(time);
}
```

Compilation options:

```bash
/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -isystem /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.4/include -std=gnu++20 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk -fPIC -o test.cpp.o -c test.cpp
```

Comment: Add the flag `-stdlib=libc++`. Default lib might be conforming only one of the older C++ standards.

Comment: @273K Just tried - same result

Comment: Just noticed it's the homebrew llvm. I doubt you can find an answer here. Try Apple clang of xcode.

Comment: @273K I forgot to mention, but I also tried with the xcode clang, and i got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has not yet been implemented.

Here is the libc++ status page for C++20:

https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Cxx20.html

The pertinent row is:

> P0355R7 LWG Extending chrono to Calendars and Time Zones Jacksonville Partial [9]

The footnote is:

> [9] P0355: The implementation status is:
>
> - Calendars mostly done in Clang 7
> - Input parsers not done
> - Stream output Obsolete due to P1361R2
>   “Integration of chrono with text formatting”
> - Time zone and leap seconds In Progress
> - TAI clock not done
> - GPS clock not done
> - UTC clock not done

Note that this:

```
auto time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto system_time = std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(time);
```

will never portably work as there is no defined relationship between `high_resolution_clock` and `system_clock`.  On gcc these are the same clock and so `clock_cast` just performs the identity conversion.  On libc++ `high_resolution_clock` is the same as `steady_clock`, and `steady_clock` has no defined relationship to `system_clock`.

`clock_cast` will perform conversions among:  `system_clock`, `utc_clock`, `tai_clock`, `gps_clock`, `file_clock`, and any user-defined clock which defines one of these pairs of static member functions:

```
to_sys
from_sys
```

or

```
to_utc
from_utc
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33964462/576911) (section "Update for C++20") for an example of a user-defined clock which participates in the `clock_cast` infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Is there a way to use libstd++ with macos?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I don't know how.  Using my [free, open-source C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) is also an option.  But there, it is `date::clock_cast` instead of `std::chrono::clock_cast`.  And to get the time zone stuff to work, [some installation is required](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to use libstd++ on MacOs, posting here in case it helps somebody.

```bash
brew install gcc # install gcc compiler with libstd++ support

# Need to use the newly installed binaries, note that g++ without 
# an additional version number will NOT work, as it is an alias to
# the default apple-clang compiler
export CC=gcc-13
export CXX=g++-13 # or check the output of `which g++-13` if you need the full path

# The version installed from brew at the time of writing is 13, 
# but could be a different version on your machine.
```